# are RTS/CTS packets channel dependent?

Tags: ieee-802.11, network-access

RTS and CTS packets in IEEE 802.11 are for dealing with hidden node problem. If I enable this feature on channel 1, would other nodes in other channels(e.g 2) receive and respect RTS/CTS packets?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Nodes on other channels are not listening to you. That's one reason why you should always use non-overlapping channels (1,6,11)